# JIRA PowerBI Service data refresh not working

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

In my PowerBI desktop, I created a Jira dashboard report, and it works perfectly. On the Power BI desktop report, I can view all of my requested data.

Now, when I publish the report https://app.powerbi.com/ the report gets published successfully, however, when I am trying to schedule the refresh, I keep getting below error.

```
Failed to update data source credentials: The credentials provided for the Web source are invalid. (Source at https://jira.tools.com/.)
```

When I try to connect straight to my Jira, I know my credentials are accurate and working properly, and the same is true in Powerbi Desktop.

What could be the reason?

[image: Schedule Refresh Screen]

Answer (score 0):

Your Jira server might be inside the firewall/inside a private network.
So, the first thing I suggest to try is setting up a Power BI Gateway. Then configure your Power BI Service refresh via that Gateway.
Useful links:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/data-integration/gateway/service-gateway-install
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-gateway-data-sources

You'll want to do that on a Server inside your firewall & ensure Proxy settings are correctly setup - to access Internet.

If that doesn't do it - it's probably a more subtle cause (anywhere from the network configuration to how Active Directory is tied to Jira). Let us know, we'll take it from there.